# Scheduled Script not updating the Record

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have written a scheduled script in production.

Through saved search based on criteria I am reading invoice records and doing some calculations.If all the conditions and calculations done successfully,I am updating each invoice record by resetting the custom checkbox field to 'F'. When I go to particular Invoice Record to see the value its still 'T'. This only the scheduled script running on the invoice. I used both the apis, nlapisubmitrecord and nlapisubmitfield both are not working.

The following code is inside of scheduled script inside for loop. It will run for each invoice record. At the end of the each invoice record it should update the value of the checkbox to 'F'. It is not happening.

```
nlapiSubmitField('invoice', invoiceRecId, 'custom_record', 'F', true);

var checkbox = loadInvoiceRecord.getFieldValue('custom_record');

if(checkbox === 'T') {
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Checking the Value', checkbox);
    loadInvoiceRecord.setFieldValue('custom_record', 'F');
    nlapiSubmitRecord(loadInvoiceRecord, true);
}
```

It should set the field to False. But it not working as expected on the invoice Record. I have checked the custom field it has all access and permissions (edit).

Comment: Does the logging part work or do you never drop into that condition? The field name looks strange, I think that they would normally start with custbody/custcol.

Comment: Also check if the due to  field is set to store value or if it is dynamically calculated. If the latter, setting it won't ever work I'm afraid.